# getting syntax error while running rails s -e production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

After running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV="production"
```

I run `rails s -e production` but I am getting following error and server is not starting.

```
rails s -e production

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting 

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require':
C:/Users/app/models/~$Meeting.rb:1: Invalid char `\x03' in expression (SyntaxError)>         from 
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
```

But running the application on development is working fine.